# Based addressing mode assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

I am taking my first assembly programming class and my instructor wants us to find out how 
based addressing mode works. So here is some code that I wrote to try and do that.
Only problem is that I must not understand it because I keep getting a segmentation fault.
I commented on the lines to try and show what I THINK they are doing.
Can someone please correct my misunderstanding.

Thanks!

```
.text
.global _start
L0: .int 0x99999999
L1: .int 0x12345678
L2: .int 0x11111111
_start:
movl $L1, %eax   #Stores the address of what L1 "pionts to" in regester eax
movb $0, 2(%eax)  #Stores 0 in the location eax has in it +2 memory locations
              #So 0 should be stored in the same place as L1+2
checkHere:


movl $1,%eax
movl $0,%ebx
int $0x80
```

Comment: syscall 1h is exit() by the way, what is your intention in _start? Also, be wary of addressing below the beginning of ELF paged address space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text` is readonly. Put your data in `.data` and it should work.